# PHP Server Side triggering after database update

Tags: php, mysql, server-sent-events

I am building a simple application test case that involves the following workflow:

A javascript script running on a third party website pushes a post stream using fetch to my server, where there is a php script listening (<**api_listen.php**>).  This listening script takes the data from the post and inserts it into a mysql database.

This part works perfectly now.

I have a simple public facing page (<**view.php**>) that loads the most recent database entry, and I'd like to use SSE to update the page each time a new record is added to the database.  I can write a script (<**sse_updates.php**>) that can query the database and send SSE updates to the <**view.php**> page.

No problem.

However...

The only way I've seen examples of this is to do a while loop and constantly query the database within the <**sse_updates.php**> file.  Because the database updates can be as short as 5 seconds, I'd have to poll the DB every 5 seconds which isn't the worst thing in the world.  I'd also have to keep track of each db record id that has been received and then forwarded via the sse stream.  Just in case there's a network lag and the <**api_listen.php**> script receives more than 1 api call within 5 seconds.

So I'm wondering if it's possible for <**api_listen.php**> to trigger <**sse_updates.php**> to do its thing every time <**api_listen.php**> receives an api call and inserts a new database record.

If I put an `include("sse_updates.php");` after the database insert is complete, would that trigger <**sse_updates.php**> to send a message to the public page? It might, but that doesn't seem the right way to do it.

This is a small private project, no need to scale as it's going to be run internally and viewed by only a few people at a time.

I hope I was able to explain my challenge clearly, and thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: You probably need Websockets to be able to do what you're suggesting, rather than just AJAX+SQL+SSE.

Comment: `no need to scale`...then is the SSE polling the DB really going to be that disastrous, if there's only one instance? Make sure it doesn't lock the table, that's all.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I think I was really curious if there's a way for one php script to trigger another, rather than using a while loop.  As soon as the api script gets called, it updates the database, and then triggers the second php script that sends the SSE data to the public facing page.

Comment: No because you need a pre-existing SSE connection with the browser (which has to be initiated by the browser) and a new instance of the PHP script wouldn't have that.